# How to remove comments on VSCode editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to remove comments from a document manually(using VSCode editor function)?

I'm making a extension.

I've added comments by program.

[image]

Comment: select the text and press `Delete`, or you need to be more detailed what you are trying to do, why does your screen shot have a Peek window (the blue lines)

Comment: I couldn't remove comment even though deleted all texts.

Comment: copy and paste the content of that file as an edit to the question, maybe open the file in a different editor to be sure of the content, also use the VSC hexeditor to see what's inside the file

Comment: In short, no function of VSCode to remove comments, need to create another file.